# PHP mysqli_fetch_all to get total rows and data together

Tags: php, mysql

I used to working on Oracle DB with PHP.

```
$strSQL = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM tb_users");
oci_execute($strSQL);
$Num_Rows = oci_fetch_all($strSQL, $dData);
```

That above code is working OK. I can get total rows and show the data using variable `$dData[]`

And now I'm using mySQL DB with PHP.

```
$strSQL = mysqli_query($c1, "SELECT * FROM tb_users");
$Num_Rows = mysqli_fetch_all($strSQL, $dData);
```

When I try to run the code (mySQL), the value of $Num_Rows is empty (I'm sure there is an data on db). And the data is not show using `$dData`.

My question, is `mysqli_fetch_all` correct?
Or is there another way?

Comment: use [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to get number of record from your table

Comment: If I use `mysqli_num_rows`, I can't call $dData[] to get data

Comment: what type is $dData?

Comment: Second parameter looks incorrect. `This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH.`

Answer (score 0):

```
$strSQL = mysqli_query($c1, "SELECT * FROM tb_users");
$Num_Rows = mysqli_fetch_all($strSQL, $dData);
```

if you use loop then it will give result for individual record

```
while($Num_Rows = mysqli_fetch_all($strSQL, $dData)){
print_r($Num_Rows);
}
```

if you want number of rows then just

```
$num_rows=count($Num_Rows)
```

OR Use

```
mysqli_num_rows
```